# Add map value to firestore document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
.set({
    //how do i add a variable here : {

          }
    })
```

I can add the map but I can't use a variable to set the name of the map

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SO! Can you please be a bit more elaborate on the problems you're having? Please share more code and describe your issues a bit better.

Comment: I need to add a map to a document in my database but i need to name my map with a variable. When I just put the variable there , for example 'x' , then the name of the map just become 'x'.

Comment: Please share the complete code with us. Without it we're unable to help you properly.

Comment: function test(){

    database.collection("orders").doc("orderNumber").get().then((doc) => {
    itemCount++;
    var orderNumberString = "order_number_" + String(doc.data().orderNumber);
    database.collection("orders").doc(orderNumberString).set({
    itemCount: {
        "modelName": document.getElementById("modelSelect").options[document.getElementById("modelSelect").selectedIndex].text,
    
          }
    })
});
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the field name come from a map, use:

```
var fieldName = "nameOfField";
ref.set({
  [fieldName]: "value"
});
```